# Angular2- Sorting the data based on dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, angular

In my angular2 application I have a drop down menu with id's and below my drop down menu I have a table which display all the values from the tables and the column names . I need to sort the data based on my selection in drop down menu. presently what ever selection I made the data is not getting sorted. Any suggestion or any links how to achieve this will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow. please take the time to read the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to know how to post answerable questions